# Connect to Remote MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

My friend recently allowed me to use his web hosting for a site I have, and he went and got all the ftp and database setup and I can do the ftp for it, but, when I try to go into the database using something like heidisql or mysql toolkit it gives me an error:
Host'XX-XXX-XXX-XXXX.dhcp.unas.al.charter.com' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server.  I called charter and they said they couldn't do anything on their end so I am assuming it may be a setting in his cpanel on his server to allow remote access to it?

Or if I'm completely off, how would this work?

EDIT: I would like to know how to get it to work by going to a cmd line and running a local mysql.exe and then connecting -u user -p -h xxx.xxx.x.xx

Comment: try to connect via an http tunnel - heidi instructions here http://mysql-tools.com/articles/http-tunnel/73-heidisql-a-http-tunnel.html

Answer (score 2):

No, Charter wouldn't be able to do anything about it, because that's an error coming [directly from the MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_host_not_privileged), because your IP address is not among the hosts configured for access.

```
Error: 1130 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED)
Message: Host '%s' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

The correct solution involves understanding that the [MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-names.html) treats username + host IP address or name where the connection is originating as an "account" -- not username by itself.

```
'foo'@'localhost'   # username foo connecting from the server machine
'foo'@'192.168.1.1' # username foo from IP address 192.168.1.1
'foo'@'192.168.1.%' # username foo from IP address 192.168.1.*
'foo'@'192.168.%'   # username foo from IP address 192.168.*.*
'foo'@'%'           # username foo from any IP address
```

In MySQL's privilege system, these are 5 different "users," potentially with 5 different passwords.  If no users are allowed to connect from your IP address or any wildcard address that matches yours, this would be the message you'd get.  This is explained further, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-access.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/access-denied.html).

There is nothing you can do with the `mysql` command line client to override the server's configuration, though you could use an SSH tunnel so that the server would think you are connecting from `localhost` or another trusted host, as was suggested in a comment.

The fix it is for your friend to grant privileges to you at your address [with a `GRANT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html).  cPanel might provide an interface to do this -- I have no idea, since I work directly with MySQL -- but if it does, that would be cPanel essentially writing the same `GRANT` statement and sending it to the MySQL server to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Error 1130 is a networking error. The server cannot resolve the hostname of the client. Or the host is not allowed to connect to the MySQL server.

There are basically 2 categories of possible reasons:

- The simple one:

In MySQL a user a user is specified using BOTH the user name and the host from where the user may connect. If no user has been created where the host-part (using wildcards or not) mathces the host of the client trying to connect MySQL will return this error.

- The tricky ones:

1)

Your hosts file is damaged or invalid. Various vira and spyware attack and alter the host file in various ways. For instance if the hosts file does not contain the line

127.0.0.1 localhost

'localhost' cant' be resolved as pointing to ip 127.0.0.1. On some larger corporate network it is widely used to "roll out" host files to all clients with symbolic names (like 'mysqlserver', 'mailserver' etc.) for important machines on the network and the corresponding ip's. Check with your admin that you got the right file!

2)

If you use the Windows network name as hostname, it may be a network configuration problem. Try using the ip instead.

This link can be helpful:

http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/36/en/i-get-error-1130-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-or-access-denied-or-could-not-connect-.html