# Docker mysql host not privileged

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, fig

I am trying to configure a nodejs container to connect to a mysql database.

My code looks like this:

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'mysql',
    port     : '3306',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '...',
    database : 'general',
    connectionLimit : 50,
    queueLimit : 5000
});
```

I am using the standard [mysql](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) container.

I am using fig for starting the containers. fig.yml looks something like:

```
node:
  build: node
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    - "9001:9001"
  links:
    - mysql:mysql
  command: node server/Main.js

mysql:
  image: mysql
  volumes:
    - /data/test:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ...
```

Every time i try to connect i get the following error:

```
failed to connect to database: Error: ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED: Host '172.17.0.142' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have played around with wordpress and it seems to connect to the same mysql db without any problems.

Thx!

**Edit**
So, I have found the answer in the end. The problem was indeed a privilege issue. I ran the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

And I was able to access the database.

Comment: Could [this be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943615/connect-to-remote-mysql-database)? Or possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)?

Comment: What is your mysql version?`General` is a reserved word in mysql 5.6,use back ticks in your pool

Comment: @wassgren I do not think it is a grant privilege issue, since wordpress connects to the same database without additional privileges

Comment: @Mihai mysql version is indeed 5.6, but the same pool used for localhost works like a charm

Comment: @Petru Ok, just to be clear. *The same database*, is that just the same server or actually *the same logical database*? Typically wordpress connects to a *wordpress*-database using the *wordpress*-user and that user has specified privileges for that particular database.

Comment: @wassgren the same logical database. First startup of the mysql docker container creates a default empty database. I was able to initialize a wordpress website on the empty database (so I am guessing they use root user for running the initialization scripts), while my node pool throws host_not_privilegeed exception when trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I use the drakedroid/mysql-with-data (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/drakedroid/mysql-with-data/) image.  It extends the default image, but adds more functionality.